# "Good at" or "Good in"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, at-in

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“At” vs. “in” before verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92326/at-vs-in-before-verb)

"He is good in painting" or "He is good at painting" — which one is correct?

Answer (score 14):

There's only one major case that leaps to mind where "good in" is idiomatically correct:

> He is good in bed.

This can be generalized somewhat to "he is good in (location where certain stereotypical activities are performed)", like saying "he is good in the field" to mean he is good at doing the tasks that need to be done in the field.

Comment: Good - I thought of "good in bed", but hadn't noticed it was extensible. But I concur that its complement must be a place, not an activity.

Comment: @Hellion: Thanks for this answer! And yes, someone can be good in a particular field of study or endeavor. Examples: `He's good in defense`; `She's good in acrobatics`; `They're good in the classroom` (meaning well-behaved); `He's amazingly good in [the subject of] analysis`.

Comment: @Jimi Oke, all of those except the classroom one (which is a location, hence subject to the exception noted by @Hellion) would sound more idiomatic using "at" instead of "in".

Comment: @Martha: In the first example, I used "defense" in a soccer sense. *At* won't sound more idiomatic in such a case and *defense* is really a location/position on the field. In many cases having to do with ranking or assessment, using *good in* sounds idiomatic. Consider: "She's the top student in biology, but in French, she is not so good." Usually, *class* is implied when this form is used, so one can still think of it as a location. I concede that maybe my other examples were not idiomatic. Other examples would be "good in general" and "good in several respects/that regard".

Comment: @Jimi Oke: in the soccer (or other sports) sense, I would tend to say "he's good on defense" rather than "in".

Comment: @Hellion: Hmm, true. I guess I'm fighting a lost cause here ;)

Comment: @Jimi Oke, @Hellion: In the homeland of "soccer" we would definitely say "he's good *in* defence" (and spell it like that too :-)

Comment: @psmears: Thanks for backing me up on this one :) I grew up saying "good *in* defence", and spelling it that way, too! Well, until I came to the US!

Answer (score 3):

If you must choose one of them:

> He is good at painting

However, you might also prefer:

> He paints well.

Comment: Even better: "He paints (x) well." where (x) is whatever he's painting (pictures, walls, etc.)

Comment: I agree that "he paints well" is better word choice.

Answer (score 3):

In general:

> He is good **in** *[location]*

and

> He is good **at** *[activity]*

Answer (score 0):

> He is good at painting.

is correct.

> He is good in painting.

is definitely incorrect — I’ve heard this form from non-native speakers, but never I think from native speakers — but its meaning is still clear; it doesn’t risk confusion.

This goes equally for any verb or activity: *she is good at climbing*, *he is terrible at football*, *I am not very good at stand-up comedy* are standard, and would be incorrect with *in*.  I can’t think of any idiomatic exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

I recently found it "The key to you for a successful class will depend in most
part by how **good** you are **in** listening, questioning, note
taking and studying and most important, test taking.

Read more: http://www.free-ebooks.net/ebook/An-Instructor-s-View-on-Student-Success/html#ixzz1ghTDV9XS

Comment: This author actually gets all of his prepositions wrong. Correct English: "**Your** key **to** a successful class will depend **for the** most part **on** how good you are **at** listening, questioning, note taking, studying and, most importantly, test taking.

Answer (score -2):

Grammar rules:

- *good at* + subject/topic

  > - She's good at Chemistry.
  > - He's good at Listening.
- *good in* + skill

  > She's good in listening.