# good AT vs. good IN

Tags: prepositions

Can I say "I am good AT math" or "I am good IN math".Are there rules for these or I can use eithe. And do they differ in meaning if I use AT or IN?

Comment: What is the context in which you are using the phrase?

Comment: In a casual conversation where one shared what he was good IN/At.

Comment: Should really be asked at http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You are good ***at*** something - duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7307/good-at-or-good-in which is a duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92326/at-vs-in-before-verb - next time you ask a question, please pay attention to the suggested duplicates that appear when you ask

Comment: As per mplungjan's comment : You should use the preposition "at" here..

Answer (score 0):

You should use "**good at**" as it suggests that you are able to do that thing. Here, good at Math means you have ability to solve math problems.

"**Good in** " doesn't serve this purpose..